# Is it okey to use evt.consume() in this case?

Tags: java, awt, textfield

So I have a textfield which I want to be max length 10 and only letters, this is what I've came up with:

```
private void textField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    
    char c= evt.getKeyChar();
    if( !(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) ){
        evt.consume();   
    }
    if ((textField1.getText().length()) > 10){
        evt.consume();
    }  
}
```

It kind of works but I've seen some tutorials that use something like this:

```
private void textField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    
    char c= evt.getKeyChar();
    if( (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) ){
        if((textField1.getText().length()) <= 10){
            textField1.setEditable(true);
        }else {
            textField1.setEditable(false);
        } 
    }else {
        if( (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) ){
            textField1.setEditable(true);
        }else {
            textField1.setEditable(false);
        }
    }
 }
```

Which one is right?

Comment: Is this a Swing GUI? If so, then neither is correct, and the best solution would be to add a DocumentFilter to the text field's Document. Please review MadProgrammer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24473097/522444).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will stop the text-field from consuming further keys.

1. calling [`InputEvent.consume()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume--) marks the event as consumed, so that the textfield will not consume it and add the key to it's contents.
   See [What does e.consume() do in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550548/what-does-e-consume-do-in-java)
2. disabling editing on the textfield with `setEditable(false)` will also prevent the textfield from editing, that is consuming the key. But it also makes this behaviour, the lock, visible to the user.